# How can i get a .odt file using rml report in openERP?

Tags: report, odoo, odt, rml

How can I get a `.odt file` using `RML report?`

I tried the code below, but the output is in .sxw format.`

```
<report auto="False"  
        id="report_sale_order" 
        model="sale.order" 
        name="sale.order"  
        report_type="odt" 
        rml="sale/report/sale_order.rml" 
        string="Quotation / Order" 
        usage="default"/>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102450/how-to-get-reports-in-odt-format-from-rml-files-in-openerp to see if it helps

Comment: same code is here. But the output is in .sxw.